# Permutation of kronecker products

Tags: permutations, tensors, kronecker-product

I would like to be able to compute a re-ordered kronecker product from the result of another kronecker product. For example, consider $$F=A\otimes B\otimes C\otimes D\otimes E$$  from the result F and the sizes of the different matrices (The matrices $A, B, C, D$  and $E$ themselves are not known!), I would like to get the result of say, $$H=A\otimes C\otimes D\otimes B\otimes E$$ which is just a re-ordering of $F$.

Is there any good algorithm for doing this and doing it efficiently for possibly very large matrices?

Comment: This just amounts to a permutation similarity

Comment: Do we have the sizes of $A,B,C,D,E$?

Comment: Yes we know the sizes of each matrix and the order in which they occur in the kronecker product.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to generalize for different sizes of the matrices, but here goes my answer:

Try to show the following lemma:

Let $T_1,\ldots,T_m \in L(V,V)$ and $A_1,\ldots,A_m$ be square matrices $n \times n$.

Show that

i) $(T_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes T_m)P(\sigma)=P(\sigma)(T_{\sigma(1)} \otimes \cdots \otimes T_{\sigma(m)})$

ii) There exists a permutation matrix $Q$ such that $A_{\sigma(1)} \otimes \cdots \otimes A_{\sigma(m)}=Q(A_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes A_m)Q^{T}$. Hint: Use i).

Comment: The matrices are not necessarily square.

Comment: You can use that there exist permutation matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that $A \otimes B = P(B \otimes A)Q$. If $A$ and $B$ are square matrices, then we can take $Q=P^{T}$.

Comment: Dear Leafar, I am looking for a way to find those matrices. I do already know they exist. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

We want $U,V^T$ such that

$$A_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes A_k = U(A_{\rho(1)} \otimes \cdots \otimes A_{\rho(k)})V^T.$$
Suppose that $A_i \in \mathbb{R}^{n_i \times m_i}$. The *row* permutation matrix $U$ can be computed as:

```
ns = [n1, ..., nk]
d = np.prod(ns)
p = np.arange(d).reshape(ns)
st = np.r_[1, ns[:0:-1]].cumprod()[::-1][rho]                              
st *= p.dtype.itemsize
q = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(p, shape=sh, strides=st)                       
U = np.eye(d)[q]
```

(Note that the permutation `rho` is taken to be zero-based in the code.) The same idea is used to compute $V$.